# I'm trying to compare two images using LockBits but it doesn't work - why?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the method:

```
public static Bitmap FastComparison(Bitmap bmp1,Bitmap bmp2)
{
            Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(512,512);
            PixelFormat pxf = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
            BitmapData bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);
            BitmapData bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);
            BitmapData bmpData3 = bmp3.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);

            IntPtr ptr1 = bmpData1.Scan0;
            IntPtr ptr2 = bmpData2.Scan0;
            IntPtr ptr3 = bmpData3.Scan0;

            int numBytes = bmpData1.Stride * bmp1.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues1 = new byte[numBytes];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr1, rgbValues1, 0, numBytes);
            bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);

            byte[] rgbValues2 = new byte[numBytes];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr2, rgbValues2, 0, numBytes);
            bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);


            for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues1.Length; counter += 3)
            {
                int  dr, dg, db;
                dr = (int)rgbValues1[counter] - (int)rgbValues2[counter];
                dg = (int)rgbValues1[counter + 1] - (int)rgbValues2[counter + 1];
                db = (int)rgbValues1[counter + 2] - (int)rgbValues2[counter + 2];

                int error = dr * dr + dg * dg + db * db;
                if (error < tolerancenumeric)
                {
                    rgbValues1[counter] = 0;
                    rgbValues1[counter + 1] = 0;
                    rgbValues1[counter + 2] = 0;
                }

            }
            Marshal.Copy(rgbValues1, 0, ptr3, numBytes);
            return bmp1;
}
```

This is how I'm using/call it in Form1:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
              CloudEnteringAlert.tolerancenum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
              pictureBox1.Image = CloudEnteringAlert.FastComparison(bitmapwithclouds, bitmapwithoutclouds);
}
```

What I want is to change the tolerance so in the end I will get a result where the image variable bmp1 will be with clouds only on black background.

What did I do wrong ?

This is the new method i changed it now . Now im getting just black image:

```
public static Bitmap FastComparison(Bitmap bmp1,Bitmap bmp2)
        {
            Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(512,512);
            PixelFormat pxf = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
            BitmapData bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);
            BitmapData bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);
            BitmapData bmpData3 = bmp3.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);

            IntPtr ptr1 = bmpData1.Scan0;
            IntPtr ptr2 = bmpData2.Scan0;
            IntPtr ptr3 = bmpData3.Scan0;

            int numBytes = bmpData1.Stride * bmp1.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues1 = new byte[numBytes];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr1, rgbValues1, 0, numBytes);
            bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);

            byte[] rgbValues2 = new byte[numBytes];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr2, rgbValues2, 0, numBytes);
            bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);


            for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues1.Length; counter += 3)
            {
                int  dr, dg, db;
                dr = (int)rgbValues1[counter] - (int)rgbValues2[counter];
                dg = (int)rgbValues1[counter + 1] - (int)rgbValues2[counter + 1];
                db = (int)rgbValues1[counter + 2] - (int)rgbValues2[counter + 2];

                int error = tolerancenumeric * tolerancenumeric + tolerancenumeric + tolerancenumeric + tolerancenumeric * tolerancenumeric;//dr * dr + dg * dg + db * db;
                if (error < tolerancenumeric)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    rgbValues1[counter] = 0;
                    rgbValues1[counter + 1] = 0;
                    rgbValues1[counter + 2] = 0;
                }

            }
            Marshal.Copy(rgbValues1, 0, ptr3, numBytes);
            bmp3.UnlockBits(bmpData3);
            return bmp3;
        }
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a very descriptive... well, description. Tell us what you expected, tell us what you received instead.

Comment: What goes wrong? And what pixel values will be set, if difference is out of tolerance?

Comment: There are some *very* obvious mistakes here.  The worst one is returning bmp1 when the result is stored in bmp3 and not unlocking bmp3.

Comment: I expected that the bmp1 that is a radar image with clouds inside i will see more and more only the clouds when changing the tolerance using the numericupdown in Form1. But the result is that there is no change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't set any pixel value for pixels that exceed your tolerance. In other cases you set them to black. Black is actually default, so you only need to set the "error" pixels.

Also you should return bmp3 (which needs to be unlocked, btw), not bmp1.

Finally, bmp3 should be created with size of bmp1 or bmp2 (which need to be the same).

Comment: JeffRSon i change the method(updated my question with the changes) but i guess setting the pixels/colors to the rgbValues1 is wrong inside the IF.  Can you show me please how to fix it ?

Comment: bmp3 is 512,512 its the size of the bmp1 and bmp2

Comment: What about `rgbValues1[counter] = dr;                  rgbValues1[counter + 1] = dg; rgbValues1[counter + 2] = db;`? Or copy values from bmp1 (before you overwrite rgbvalue1.

Comment: Why rgbValues1[counter] = dr; is not working ? counter and dr are both type int but im getting error say it cant convert byte to int.

Comment: It's probably the other way around: Use `rgbValues1[counter] = (byte)dr;` a.s.o.